# Inserting data into SQL Server 2014 in C# (Visual 2015) using classes and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

I have a problem inserting data in my SQL Server database. 
I'm using a class called book and in my form design when I want to insert data I receive an error.

```
class Book
{
    private string _bookname;
    private int _bookcode;
    private int _numberofpages;
    private string _author;
    private string _publicationname;
    private string _genre;
    private int _publishyear;
    private string _language;
     SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();

    public Book(SqlConnection sqlcon)
    {
        _sqlcon = sqlcon;
    }

    public string bookname
    {
        get { return _bookname; }
        set { _bookname = value; }
    }
    public int bookcode
    { 
    get { return _bookcode; }
    set { _bookcode = value; }
        }
    public int numberofpages
    {
        get { return _numberofpages; }
        set { _numberofpages = value; }

    }
    public string author
    {
        get { return _author; }
        set { _author = value; }
    }
    public string publicationname
        {
        get { return _publicationname; }
        set { _publicationname = value; }
        }
    public string genre
    {
        get { return _genre; }
        set { _genre = value; }
    }
    public int publishyear
    {
        get { return _publishyear; }
        set { _publishyear = value; }
    }
    public string language
    {
        get { return _language; }
        set { _language = value; }
    }

    public void SaveBook()
    {
        SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Connection = _sqlcon;
        com.CommandText = "PROC_BOOK1";
        com.Parameters.Add("@nameofbook", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = bookname;
        com.Parameters.Add("@codeofbook", SqlDbType.Int).Value = bookcode;
        com.Parameters.Add("@npages", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numberofpages;
        com.Parameters.Add("@bookauthor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = author;
        com.Parameters.Add("@publicationname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = publicationname;
        com.Parameters.Add("@bookgenre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = genre;
        com.Parameters.Add("@pyear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = publishyear;
        com.Parameters.Add("@booklanguage", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = language;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and this is my insert button:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
    private Book _book1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnsabt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _book1 = new Book(_sqlcon);
        _book1.bookname = txtbookname.Text;
        _book1.bookcode = Convert.ToInt32(txtbookcode.Text);
        _book1.numberofpages = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumberofpages.Text);
        _book1.author = txtauthor.Text;
        _book1.publicationname = txtpublication.Text;
        _book1.genre = txtgenre.Text;
        _book1.publishyear = Convert.ToInt32(txtpublishyear.Text);
        _book1.language = txtlanguage.Text;
        _book1.SaveBook();
        MessageBox.Show("saved succesfully");

    }
```

Below is the error snapshot:

[image]

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: You are creating too many SqlConnection objects whereas you just need 1. I also cant see the ConnectionString property being populated with a valid conneciton string.
Either create the new object of SqlConnection in the SaveBook method or pass it in the constructor from the client code i.e. button click..

Comment: Post the error in the question itself. *Don't* post a link to an image that may disappear next minute and can't be googled.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is in the way you have designed this Book model.

You force you users to use a constructor that receives an SqlConnection and then (this is probably just an error) you create a new instance of the SqlConnection (without a connectionstring) in the SaveBook method.
Probably you wish to use the SqlConnection passed in the constructor and you expect the clients of this class to initialize it with a proper setting for the connectionstring and open it.

So, if you really want your clients to provide the connection, then initialize it with the connectionstring and open it BEFORE initilizing the Book instance in the click method. Of course remove the line that creates a new connection in the SaveBook method.

```
public void SaveBook()
{
    // This line defines a local variable with the same name of the global one
    // It hides the global, if you expect your client to provide the connection
    // then remove the line
    SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
    ....
```

I find this design not very wise. It is a hornet's nest already starting to sting you in every possible way.

The model (Book) should not concern itself on how it is saved to its final storage (or loaded from) being it a database table, an XML file, a remote service or whatever you need to do in future.

Instead, a dedicated class to handle the database transactions should have all the code to save and retrieve the Book data from the Database table (in this case)

I would have designed it with a class named BookDB

```
public class BookDB
{
     public bool Save(Book obj)
     {
          using(SqlConnection con = RepositoryUtility.GetConnection())
          {
              // here code to check and save the object
              ....
          }
     }
     public Book LoadByKey(int bookID)
     {
          using(SqlConnection con = RepositoryUtility.GetConnection())
          {
              Book aBook = new Book();
              // here goes the code to load a book from the db using the primarykey
              ....
              return aBook
          }
     }
     ... other db methods based ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, did what you said but I still get the previous error about com.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Difficult to help you on this. Do you initialize the connectionstring? Did you open the connection? Could you add an [edit] to your question showing the changes applied (do not alter the original code, just add the change made)

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory,you need to open your connection unless the connection is closed you'll get that error

```
    SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
    _sqlcon.Open(); 
     .
     .//other codes    
     .
   _sqlcon.Close();//at the end close your connection
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are not opening the connection. You should have a connection string and do something like this with that connection object:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();

        ...do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your SaveBook method.

```
SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
            _sqlcon.ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE = <sql server instance name>; INITIAL CATALOG = <database name>; INTEGRATED SECURITY = SSPI";
            _sqlcon.Open();
```

You need to open the _sqlCon object and assign a conneciton string to your sql database server.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just edit this:

```
com.connection.open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
com.connection.close();
```

You need to open connection before you can execute your queries against the database, and then close it after you are done.